# Is it possible to let PowerShell interact with a console application?

Tags: powershell

Let say you have any console application that is easily to start, later when the console has been running for a while maybe it outputs something in the console window and wait for user interaction. Is it possible to let PowerShell answer to this output?

So this is what I want to do in PowerShell:

1. Start MyApp.exe
2. Wait for some output
3. Depending on the output provide input to MyApp.exe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the normal .NET APIs for that from PowerShell, i.e. [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx), getting input and output stream of the process and act on that accordingly. Directly it is not possible.

Comment: To bad my exe-file I tried to run didn't behave as I expected so had to find another solution, but this is the answer to question i asked.